# PCI Compliance Password time to die change requirement

Tags: pci-dss, legal

In the PCI DSS3 requirements it states that the user must change their password every 90 days, how are banks in the UK getting around this requirement? Is it because of 2FA?

As a new business we are analysing the requirements and what we need to do and this one in particular seems extreme when most companies aren't requiring it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you are talking about customers of the bank not being required to change their password every 90 days.

Customers of the bank are not covered by PCI; PCI dictates what employees and others working on the infrastructure within PCI scope are required to do.  To quote [PCI DSS 3.2.1](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2-1.pdf?agreement=true&time=1612795992533) Requirement 8 (emphasis mine):

> Note: These requirements are applicable for all accounts, including
> point-of-sale accounts, with administrative capabilities and all
> accounts used to view or access cardholder data or to access systems
> with cardholder data. This includes accounts used by vendors and other
> third parties (for example, for support or maintenance). **These
> requirements do not apply to accounts used by consumers (e.g.,
> cardholders).**

Comment: Additionally, any PCI QSA worth their salt will ignore this requirement where a more suitable control is implemented. If there's 2FA and accounts are frequently being audited, there's absolutely no need for password cycling, and it can even be detrimental. NCSC have been advising against password cycling for 6 years now.